# RealityKit – How to create shadow catcher for natural lighting?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'd like to create a plane:

```
func getShadowPlane(_ width: Float, _ height: Float) -> ModelEntity {

    let sphereResource = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: width, 
                                                    depth: height)
    let myMaterial = ShadowMataerial . ????
    return ModelEntity(mesh: sphereResource, materials: [myMaterial])
}
```

& add it to my anchor at specific position.
I'd like to get shadow data from the "lighting" I get from my camera that RealityKit is able to capture/generate.

I don't want to use

```
AnchorEntity(plane: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment.horizontal)
```

Any idea how can this be accomplished?

I can not find shadowCatcher material.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's NO formula for catching only shadows in RealityKit 2.0, like SceneKit's:

```
SCNMaterial().lightingModel = .shadowOnly
```

However, you can use [Fake Shadows](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c) based on `.png` image or you can implement [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) to separately catch a shadow.

Comment: Is there a way to import SceneKits plane/floor/shadow in to RealityKit ?
I mean, I've no idea how it all work because they both use ARView & scene. So are they interchangeable ?

Comment: They are not interchangeable! They are totally different. SceneKit+ARKit use ARSCNView, but RealityKit uses ARView.

Comment: Andy, are you familiar with any open source that utilizes metal to show shadows in RealityKit?

Comment: @Nativ, No, unfortunately I'm not good at Metal.